# How to integrate various devices with browser using HTML5?

Tags: html, mobile, integration

I am working on a POS kind of application and now the requirement is to integrate various devices with the application like camera,Magnetic card reader,Printers etc. Can any one share link that How to use HTML5 to integrate various devices with the application built using HTML5. ?

Comment: That has nothing much to do with HTML5 anymore, you need at least a browser plugin of some kind, or a client-side app in native code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no HTML5 API for cameras, card readers or the other hardware devices you mention. Probably the best option is to create a 'hybrid' application using technologies such as [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com).

PhoneGap executes your HTML5 application within a native wrapper. This allows it to expose hardware functionality to your code via  JavaScript API.

Comment: ..can you please share some links which can detail you answer so that I can try your approach.. thanks for this..

Comment: Is there no other solution..I dont want to rely on third party utility called as phonegap,also what if I have connected camera or card reader with my desktop,can my browser application connect with them as well?